# Xcode - Interface Builder and iPhone 5 images

Tags: xcode, interface, interface-builder, iphone-5

I'm using IB to assign images to UIImageViews. I know that for retina images you need two images: the non-retina resolution .png and the @2x.png. I just assign the normal image in IB and when the device is retina it gets the @2x, everything OK.

But how about the iPhone 5 images? Is there some kind of suffix for IB to read and swap the image as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

You can use:

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)
```

to check if the user is using iPhone 5 or not.

In some cases I use the iPhone 5 image as the @2x picture to avoid the check above. The iPhone 5 user will get a full resolution picture and the iPhone 4 user will get the same picture but with an hidden lower part.

Comment: Just note that you cannot use the macro in `#if` statements, as it isn't a compile-time expression. Use it in a normal `if` statement, and you'll be fine.